# jQuery method can not deliver data to REST server

Tags: javascript, jquery, spring-restcontroller

These codes are about jQuery JavaScript which deliver data to RESTful Server of Spring Boot. First, below codes are Rest Controller sources.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/user")
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("login")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> authenticated(@RequestBody User user) {

        System.out.println(user.getUsername() + user.getPassword()); // return values are NULL

        Boolean blogin = userService.authenticate(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
        if(!blogin)
            return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(blogin, HttpStatus.NOT_ACCEPTABLE);

        return new ResponseEntity<Boolean>(blogin, HttpStatus.OK);
    }
}
```

And the jQuery JavaScript codes.

**== index.html ==**

```
<html>
<head>
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<title>Login</title>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="/js/ajaxlogin.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Please sign in</h1>
    <form method="post" id="loginForm" th:object="${loginForm}">
        <div><label for="username">username</label></div>
        <input id="username" type="text" name="username" th:value="*{username}"/>

        <div><label for="password" th:value="*{username}">password</label></div>
        <input id="password" type="password" name="password" th:value="*{password}" />

        <div>
            <input type="submit" value="Login" />
            <a href="index.html" th:href="@{/posts}">Cancel</a>
        </div>
    </form>
    <div id=helloUserDiv></div>
</body>
</html>
```

**== ajaxlogin.js ==**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#loginForm").submit(function (event) {

        //stop submit the form, we will post it manually.
        event.preventDefault();
        ajax_login_submit();
    });
});

function ajax_login_submit() {

    var user = {
        username : $("#username").val,
        password : $("#password").val
    }

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "rest/user/login/",
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        dataType: 'json',
        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {

            var resultJson = JSON.stringify(data);
            $('#helloUserDiv').html(resultJson);
            console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
            alert(data);

        },
        error: function (e) {

            var resultJson = e.responseText;
            $('#helloUserDiv').html(resultJson);
            console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        }
    });
}
```

But results are failed. The Error codes 406. I am unsure what my error is on these codes.

### Updated

I modified the JavaScript like below,

```
function ajax_login_submit() {

    var user = {
            username: $("#username").val(),
            password: $("#password").val()
        };

    console.log(user.username);
    console.log(user.password);
    console.log(user);

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        url: "rest/user/login",
        data: JSON.stringify(user),
        //dataType: 'json',
        success: function (data) {

            var resultJson = JSON.stringify(data);
            $('#helloUserDiv').html(resultJson);
            console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
            alert(data);

        },
        error: function (e) {

            var resultJson = e.responseText;
            $('#helloUserDiv').html(resultJson);
            console.log("ERROR : ", e);
        }
    });
}
```

`console.log(user)` returns the following values which are correct,

{username: "joseph", password: "password"}

But RestController bring some problems.

```
@RestController
@RequestMapping(value="/rest/user")
public class UserRestController {

    @Autowired
    private UserService userService;

    @PostMapping("login")
    public ResponseEntity<Boolean> authenticated(@RequestBody User user) {

        System.out.println(user.getUsername() + user.getPassword()); // return values are "josephnull"

        Boolean blogin = userService.authenticate(user.getUsername(), user.getPassword());
```

`System.out.println(user.getUsername() + user.getPassword());` This line returns "josephnull" i.e. I mean the password value is null. I cannot understand why the password value is null.

Comment: why do you stringify your data sent?

Comment: `data: user,` is how to send it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Error code `406` means the data is not acceptable. Here are details.
[Error code 406 details.](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Status/406)
Remove `dataType: 'json'` from your code and it will work. By having this line, code was throwing `parse error` once i remove it, the error was gone and response was successful.

Here is the working code, ignore the `url` as i have used mine.

```
$.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        contentType: "application/json",
        url: "hms/raw/login",
        data: JSON.stringify(user),

        cache: false,
        timeout: 600000,
        success: function (data) {

            var resultJson = JSON.stringify(data);
            $('#helloUserDiv').html(resultJson);
            console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
            alert(data);

        },
        error: function (e) {

            var resultJson = e.responseText;
            $('#helloUserDiv').html(resultJson);
            console.log("ERROR : ", e);
            console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
        }
    });
```

Comment: Hi, @Shahzeb  Would you check my updated Part, please?

Comment: Its working fine with me. Couldn't reproduce the issue.

Answer (score 0):

In your jquery $.ajax call try to put

`data: {user :JSON.stringify(user)},`  instead of `data:  JSON.stringify(user) ,`
or `data: {user : user},` according to your need
Then the code will be:

```
function ajax_login_submit() {

        var user = {
            username : $("#username").val,
            password : $("#password").val
        }

        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            contentType: "application/json",
            url: "rest/user/login/",
            data: data: {user :JSON.stringify(user)},
            dataType: 'json',
            cache: false,
            timeout: 600000,
            success: function (data) {

                var resultJson = JSON.stringify(data);
                $('#helloUserDiv').html(resultJson);
                console.log("SUCCESS : ", data);
                alert(data);

            },
            error: function (e) {

                var resultJson = e.responseText;
                $('#helloUserDiv').html(resultJson);
                console.log("ERROR : ", e);
            }
        });
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

You can post data by using FormData() like:

```
var data = new FormData();
data.set('key', 'value');
```

If you want to send image then

```
data.append('image', imageFile);
```

Then set header `headers: {'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data'` and send it without stringify.

It should look like this:

```
$.ajax({
     type: "POST",
     contentType: "multipart/form-data",
     url: "to/url",
     data: data,
     success: function (data) {
         alert(data);
     }
});
```